# execute a python script from another one and get the output

Tags: python

I have already searched in the forum but I have not found anything that solves my problem. I have two simple script P1 and P2. P1 should execute P2 and should print its return value

P1

```
 import sys
 import subprocess

 sys.path.append('/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/')

 output = subprocess.check_output('python P2.py', shell=True)

 print output
```

P2

```
 def foo():
   var1 = 3
   var2 = 6
   return var1 + var2

 foo()
```

if I run P1 I don't receive anything as output but if I run P2 it prints correctly the value 9. What's wrong ? thanks

Comment: It doesn't look to me like P2 is returning anything.

Comment: As @John suggests, you might conclude P2 with `print foo()`

Comment: why not? foo function returns 9. Or not ?

Comment: not.  P2 isn't outputting anything so check_output isn't returning anything.  If your run 'python P2.py' from the command line you won't see any output.  Technically it is returning 0 to note that it executed successfully but that's not what you get from check_output

Comment: Also, it's usually a good idea to avoid shell=True if you can and in this case calling check_output(['python','P2.py']) provides the same functionality without the risk.

Comment: Thanks both you for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're being tricked by your IDE into thinking that `P2.py` has output that it does not have.  Sometimes IDEs will print things that are useful for debugging but that shouldn't be confused with the output of your script.  Your `foo()` function returns 9 but `P2.py` doesn't *output* 9.

check_output only returns things that are printed from the subprocess (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)).  Currently, `P2.py` doesn't print anything.  It only calculates a value of 9 and exits so your string `output` in `P1.py` is empty.  You never ask it to do anything with the value of `foo()` so nothing is done.  Replace `foo()` in `P2.py` with `print foo()` to achieve your desired behavior.

Comment: thanks u a lot. In fact, i thought that the return value of P2 script was 9

Comment: Yeah.  The return value is 0 which just indicates successful execution.  If you had managed to change that to any other number check_output would have thrown an error.  I'm not sure what you're wanting to use this for eventually, but you should be aware that your output variable is a string as currently written and you might get some unexpected behavior if you don't convert it back to a number before using it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a function from another file you need to `import filename` (if they are in the same directory) and then you can execute it with `filename.functionName(variables)`

Edit: that's for python 3.x

Comment: thanks for the answer. they are in the same directory, but I don't wont to use `foo()` in the p1 script. I just want p1 executes p2 and prints out its return value.